# Perl regex find line with un commented code

Tags: regex, perl

Consider the following C/C++ lines of code

```
/* Comment header int a = 10; Comment footer */
/* Comment header */ /* Comment footer */
/* Comment header */ int a = 10; /* Comment footer */
```

I tried the following thing but it will not work for line 3

```
$line =~ /^\s*\/\*.*\*\/\s*$/
```

Line 1 and 2 has only comments and not code. How can I make the regex to be true only for line 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question ["How do I use a regular expression to strip C-style comments from a file?" is answered in the perl faqs](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file-). Here is the nice(ish) commented version of the regex:

```
s{
   /\*         ##  Start of /* ... */ comment
   [^*]*\*+    ##  Non-* followed by 1-or-more *'s
   (
     [^/*][^*]*\*+
   )*          ##  0-or-more things which don't start with /
               ##    but do end with '*'
   /           ##  End of /* ... */ comment

 |         ##     OR  various things which aren't comments:

   (
     "           ##  Start of " ... " string
     (
       \\.           ##  Escaped char
     |               ##    OR
       [^"\\]        ##  Non "\
     )*
     "           ##  End of " ... " string

   |         ##     OR

     '           ##  Start of ' ... ' string
     (
       \\.           ##  Escaped char
     |               ##    OR
       [^'\\]        ##  Non '\
     )*
     '           ##  End of ' ... ' string

   |         ##     OR

     .           ##  Anything other char
     [^/"'\\]*   ##  Chars which doesn't start a comment, string or escape
   )
 }{defined $2 ? $2 : ""}gxse;
```

You could use that regex directly and compare the string before to the string
after and see if anything other than whitespace is left.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic solution would be this:

```
perl -ne 'm{/\*(.*?)\*/.*\S+.*/\*(.*?)\*/} && print $_' <input file>
```

The match in the middle is very basic and matches anything that has at least one non-whitespace character, but it only gets the third line from your input.

Edit: Made more legible at the suggestion of mtm.

Comment: As mentioned in the [perl faq](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file-), matching comments is "much harder than you'd think" mainly due to things that look like comments that occur in code (like strings) and multi line spanning.

Comment: Also if you are trying to match multiple `/`s in a regex it can be slightly more legible if you use something else as the delimiter for the match: `m{/\*(.*?)\*/.*\S+.*/\*(.*?)\*/}`

Comment: Absolutely. This regex will match the scant three lines of provided information and isn't intended to be comprehensive.